# Tab bar disappears when returning back to the table view controller from another view

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift2, uitabbarcontroller

I have a table view controller connected to a tab bar controller and everything works fine. Then I have a simple view controller where the user can create a new post and I pass from the table view controller to this view with a button "new post" and then the user can either click "post" and get back to the table view or by pressing the "back" button. Everything works fine but when returning back from the view to the table view the tab bar disappears. I put the photo of the storyboard: [the main.storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maoZG.png)

Comment: Don't use a segue to return to the previous view controller.  You need to use an *unwind segue*.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13106216/1630618

Answer (score 1):

Like what @vacawama suggested you should not be using a show `segue` but a unwind `segue`. However, you can also do it in code like this if your `CustomViewController`are in a `UINavigationController`

```
@IBAction func backButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
  self.navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Or in a presented modal like this :

```
@IBAction func backButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
  self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```