# Memory leak from programmatically set constraints? iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory-leaks

I have built an app and discovered that there is a memory leak.  When I segue from my home page view controller to any other view controller and then back to my homepage, the memory grows by a small amount each time.  From everything I can tell, this is due to a problem with my home page view controller. In my ViewController class (the class for my home page) I set constraints programmatically to fit every iOS device.  Could this be a cause of my memory leak? how could I clear these constraints once I segue to a new view controller? The code for my ViewController class (homepage) can be seen below.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var GoButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var Background: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var SettingsButton: UIButton!


@IBOutlet weak var aboutButton: UIButton!


@IBAction func toFlashcards(_ sender: Any) {

    self.Background.image = nil

}

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    if(view.frame.size.width == 375 || view.frame.size.width == 812)&&(view.frame.size.height == 375 || view.frame.size.height == 812){
        iphoneX()
    }
    if(view.frame.size.width == 320 || view.frame.size.width == 568)&&(view.frame.size.height == 320 || view.frame.size.height == 568){
        iphoneSE()
    }

    if(view.frame.size.width == 414 || view.frame.size.width == 736)&&(view.frame.size.height == 414 || view.frame.size.height == 736){
        iphone8Plus()
    }

    if(view.frame.size.width == 375 || view.frame.size.width == 667)&&(view.frame.size.height == 375 || view.frame.size.height == 667){
        iphone8()
    }

    if(view.frame.size.width == 1024 || view.frame.size.width == 1366)&&(view.frame.size.height == 1024 || view.frame.size.height == 1366){
        ipadPro()
    }

    if(view.frame.size.width == 1112 || view.frame.size.width == 834)&&(view.frame.size.height == 1112 || view.frame.size.height == 834){
        ipad10inch()
    }

    if(view.frame.size.width == 768 || view.frame.size.width == 1024)&&(view.frame.size.height == 768 || view.frame.size.height == 1024){
        ipad9inch()
    }
}
func iphoneX(){
    Background.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    Background.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "iphoneXBackground")


    GoButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 50)
    GoButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 220).isActive = true
    GoButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 150).isActive = true
    view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: GoButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 88).isActive = true


    SettingsButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30)
    view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: SettingsButton.trailingAnchor, constant: 575).isActive = true
    SettingsButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 90).isActive = true
    SettingsButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 139).isActive = true


    aboutButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30)
    view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aboutButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 34).isActive = true
    aboutButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 300).isActive = true
    aboutButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 280).isActive = true
}
func iphoneSE(){
    Background.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    Background.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "iphoneXBackground")
    view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: GoButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 75).isActive = true
    GoButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 195).isActive = true
    GoButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 95).isActive = true


   view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: SettingsButton.trailingAnchor, constant: 400).isActive = true
    SettingsButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 60).isActive = true
    SettingsButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 120).isActive = true

    view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aboutButton.bottomAnchor, constant:40).isActive = true

    aboutButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 205).isActive = true
    aboutButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 245).isActive = true

    aboutButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 25)
GoButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 45)
SettingsButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 25)

}
func iphone8Plus(){
    Background.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    Background.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "iphoneXBackground")

    GoButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 50)
    view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: GoButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 94).isActive = true
    GoButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 245).isActive = true
    GoButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 130).isActive = true


    SettingsButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30)
    view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: SettingsButton.trailingAnchor, constant: 525).isActive = true
    SettingsButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 75).isActive = true
    SettingsButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 157).isActive = true


    aboutButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 32)
    view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aboutButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 46).isActive = true
    aboutButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 267).isActive = true
    aboutButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 315).isActive = true

}
func iphone8(){
    Background.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    Background.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "iphoneXBackground")

    GoButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 50)
    view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: GoButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 85).isActive = true
    GoButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 215).isActive = true
    GoButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 112).isActive = true

    SettingsButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30)
    view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: SettingsButton.trailingAnchor, constant: 465).isActive = true
    SettingsButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 65).isActive = true
    SettingsButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 139).isActive = true

    aboutButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30)
    view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aboutButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 35).isActive = true
    aboutButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 239).isActive = true
    aboutButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 284).isActive = true
}
func ipadPro(){
    Background.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    GoButton.frame.size.width = 170
    GoButton.frame.size.height = 170
    GoButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 100)
    view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: GoButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 209).isActive = true
    view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: GoButton.trailingAnchor, constant: 961).isActive = true
    GoButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 200).isActive = true

    SettingsButton.frame.size.width = 220
    SettingsButton.frame.size.height = 147
    SettingsButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 60)
    view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: SettingsButton.trailingAnchor, constant: 935).isActive = true
    SettingsButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 118).isActive = true
    SettingsButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 420).isActive = true

    aboutButton.frame.size.width = 222
    aboutButton.frame.size.height = 129
    aboutButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 60)
    view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aboutButton.trailingAnchor, constant: 667).isActive = true
    aboutButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 445).isActive = true
    view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aboutButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 94).isActive = true
}
func ipad10inch(){
    Background.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    GoButton.frame.size.width = 220
    GoButton.frame.size.height = 110
    GoButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 82)

    view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: GoButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 174).isActive = true
    view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: GoButton.trailingAnchor, constant: 810).isActive = true
    GoButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 161).isActive = true

    SettingsButton.frame.size.width = 220
    SettingsButton.frame.size.height = 110
    SettingsButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 55)
    view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: SettingsButton.trailingAnchor, constant: 737).isActive = true
    SettingsButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 92).isActive = true
    SettingsButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 335).isActive = true

    aboutButton.frame.size.width = 200
    aboutButton.frame.size.height = 108
    aboutButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 55)
    view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aboutButton.trailingAnchor, constant: 515).isActive = true
    aboutButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 338).isActive = true
    view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aboutButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 80).isActive = true
}
func ipad9inch(){
    Background.contentMode = .scaleToFill

    GoButton.frame.size.width = 220
    GoButton.frame.size.height = 110
    GoButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 82)
    view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: GoButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 160).isActive = true
    view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: GoButton.trailingAnchor, constant: 738).isActive = true
    GoButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 155).isActive = true

    SettingsButton.frame.size.width = 220
    SettingsButton.frame.size.height = 110
    SettingsButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 55)
    view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: SettingsButton.trailingAnchor, constant: 700).isActive = true
    SettingsButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 85).isActive = true
    SettingsButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 305).isActive = true

    aboutButton.frame.size.width = 200
    aboutButton.frame.size.height = 108
    aboutButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 55)
    view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aboutButton.trailingAnchor, constant: 495).isActive = true
    aboutButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 312).isActive = true
    view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aboutButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 65).isActive = true
}

}
```

Comment: FYI - you really should rethink your code. Hardcoding all of your layout for each specific device isn't scalable. The whole point of autolayout and constraints is to write it just once so it looks correct for all screen sizes.

Comment: Are you using a normal segue to return to your HomeViewController, or are you using an *unwind segue*?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13106095/1630618) if you are not using *unwind segue*.